# Filter apply "on" date but not working - EXTJS

Tags: date, extjs, grid, filtering, date-format

I am trying to filter date, before & after work proper but ON not work.

Please check screenshot.

Code :

```
 {
  text: "Updated Date", dataIndex: 'CreatedDate', groupable: false,xtype: 'datecolumn', filter: { type: 'date', active: true, dateFormat: 'm/d/Y', active: true }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your filter, besides having `active: true` twice, but that shouldn't be a problem. Can you post the code for your grid, store and some sample data from the store?

Answer (score 0):

I would write log messages by `console.log("filter :" + this.filter)` within the object and also within all interesting points to figure out the sequence of updating.

Maybe a layout update by `Objektname.doLayout()` is the solution (just an idea)?

Answer (score 0):

"on" appears to be based on a perfect match (==)
If I removed hour, minute, second from time object,  "on" than worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ticking the 'On' check box? 
I have found that if you picked a date it doesn't automatically tick the check box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
{ text: "Updated Date", dataIndex: 'CreatedDate', groupable: false,filter: true, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y')}
```

And pass these property in your CreatedDate field in Model

dateFormat: 'm/d/Y' , type: date